# Есть ли смысл выводить в отдельную библиотеку классов методы которые обрабатывают элементы формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я могу добавить методы с элементами DropDown в код формы (например заполнение свойства DataSource).
Будет ли целесообразным сделать отдельную библиотеку классов для этого чтобы не захламлять код формы (и дальнейшее использование в других WinForms проектах)?

Comment: Какой-то общий вопрос,но если ты планируешь использовать код в других проектах,тебе так удобнее или еще что-то,то смысл есть. Привязывать код к UI напрямую плохая идея,как мне кажется :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу такую мотивацию:

1. Вы хотите повторно использовать код или шарить его между проектами в одном решении
2. У вас есть какие-то личные предпочтения. Например, модели отдельная либа, доступ к данным другая и т д.
3. Вы знаете, что часть системы, которую вы хотите вынести в отдельную либу, будет меняться с другой периодичностью, чем интерфейс => в будущем вам не понадобится перекомпилировать все приложение, а просто перекомпилируете необходимую сборку.